# Complying with new Cookie Regulations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, cookies

I need to go though the projects we have worked on lately and find where we use cookies and see if our use of cookies is appropriate.  How can I search my code to do this and how would I know if the use of cookies is appropriate or not?  When I use things like Session or TempData or anything like that, should I be worried then too?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this big Cookie regulation law in UK (I hope you are talking about the same regulation) screwed my life for 3 months. The solution we proposed was to take a prior consent from the user before writing the Cookie on a user's system.

Please ignore if the regulation you are talking is different from this.

Answer (score 0):

> When I use things like Session or TempData or anything like that,
>   should I be worried then too?

Yes, you should be worried about code that adds cookies without your consent. However, I don't have any detailed information about the new cookies regulation to give you legal advice.

You could do this otherwise:

1. Crawl your website using curl, and store the returned cookies for each page.
2. Go through each different type of cookie, and check that it complies to the new regulation.

If you have pages that requires authentication, this can be a bit harder and more complicated. But it's still possible to do it with curl.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great Chrome add on that will do a cookie audit for you...

http://www.attacat.co.uk/resources/cookies

I have used it across all of my clients sites. The cookies info page generation tool is also very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this service - it will catch all cookies set by a website and classify them as third party, permanent and session. Example for CNN.com:

https://webcookies.org/