# ASP.NET - out of the box solution for the EU cookie legislation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, cookies

Does anyone have an out of the box / ready to go set of .NET files to support the EU cookie legislation? Something quick, simple and mildly customisable would be good.

Comment: maybe you should tell more about what EU cookie legislation is forcing you to do and, oh, whathaveyoutried.com?

Comment: He assumes - rightly - not every web developer is an idiot and this Thing is common knowledge by now. Basically you MUST ask the user before placing a Cookie ;) Or get into legal Trouble. More info at http://www.ico.gov.uk/for_organisations/privacy_and_electronic_communications/the_guide/cookies.aspx - and you should KNOW that stuff. THis is like "hey, i make Websites but I dont know HTML", legally.

Comment: At least let's close it for the proper reason (duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10784023/complying-with-new-cookie-regulations). Anyway, there's a jQuery plugin, called CookieGuard,  that helps with confirming user consent here: http://cookieguard.eu/

Answer (score 3):

i use this

controller:

```
public ActionResult ClearAllCookiesAndRedirect()
        {
            HttpCookie aCookie;
            string cookieName;
            int limit = Request.Cookies.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
            {
                cookieName = Request.Cookies[i].Name;
                aCookie = new HttpCookie(cookieName);
                aCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
                Response.Cookies.Add(aCookie);
            }

            return View();
        }
```

in view:

```
 HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["AcceptCookiesEULaw"];
    if (cookie == null)
    {
         //your html code here
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Little late to the party, but I created this one:
https://github.com/hudo/EUCookiesNET
You can find it on nuget also. OWIN version soon to be published.

Comment: Does it store user consent in a database or log file?